# Is there such case when in try\finally block the finally won't be executed?

Tags: java, exception, try-catch-finally, finally

I'm studying for my test in Object Oriented Programming and I was wondering if there is any case what so ever that considering the following code:

```
try {
    do something
} catch (someException e) {

} finally {
    do something
}
```

the `finally` block will not execute?

Comment: Pulling the plug should do it.

Comment: http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/My-Tales.aspx

Answer (score 17):

Yes.  If you crash the Java VM or otherwise muck things up via native code, cause the program to terminate, or loop/wait infinitely inside the `try` block.

Those are the only three cases which will avoid executing the `finally` block.

Comment: Calling System.exit or turning of the computer probably counts as "cause the program to terminate" ...  :-)

Comment: If in the try block, you return from the function containing this try/catch/finally phrase, would the finally block still execute ?

Comment: @euphoria: yes, of course, that's part of the deal, that a `finally` block is guaranteed to execute when the code inside the corresponding `try` block exits under normal circumstances (including normal exceptions)

Comment: Nitpicking: If a catch-block is executed before the finally, and endless loop/wait there will also prevent execution from reaching the finally block. Other than that, I think you got all cases :-)

Answer (score 5):

If you call `System.exit(0)` in the `try`. Or make something that makes the JVM quit or hang (like a deadlock). Otherwise - no.

Answer (score 2):

The Java Language Specification [guarantees](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/statements.html#14.20.2) that finally is invoked before the try-statement completes.

The try statement might not complete for the usual reasons, which have been enumerated in Borealid's answer.

Comment: "finally is invoked before the try-statement completes" ??? shouldn't "before" be "when"

Comment: A try-*statement* consists of the try-*block*, any catch blocks, and optionally a finally-block.

Answer (score 0):

The finally block will definitely get executed if the control comes out of the try or the catch block. If you some how manage to stop the control to come out of these blocks :

- by writing exit statement, or
- infinite loop etc.

then the finally block will not get executed.
Generally we write the finally block for the "*cleanup*" purpose.