# is there any code, that will never execute finally clause?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there such case when in try\finally block the finally won't be executed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3484353/is-there-such-case-when-in-try-finally-block-the-finally-wont-be-executed)

is there any code, that will never execute finally clause?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Java Tutorials](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html)

**Not only for System.exit , but also for thread interrupted**

> Note: If the JVM exits while the try or catch code is being executed,
>   then the finally block will not
>   execute. Likewise, if the thread
>   executing the try or catch code is
>   interrupted or killed, the finally
>   block will not execute even though the
>   application as a whole continues.

Comment: Can you clarify the point about interruption? `Thread.interrupt()` can't make thread to bypass `finally` block.

Comment: The point about killing a thread is also not clear - `Thread.stop()` causes an exception to be thrown, so that `finally` block is triggered as usual.

Comment: @axtavt: the OS can kill the thread, and the owner application will not be notified. I have seen this behavior for on app I was developing.

Answer (score 4):

`System.exit(0)` is one example.  If you compile and run below "Bye" will never get printed.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Hi");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        finally {
            System.out.println("Bye!");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`System.exit(0)` if does not throw security exception.

Answer (score 4):

Here's another example:

```
try {
    while (true) {
       System.err.println("Its great to be alive");
    }
} finally {
    System.err.println("I wish!");
}
```

Comment: @Suresh S: Well, it *technically* does what you asked for ;o)

Comment: This code can be interrupted so it should go to finally block, shouldn't it?

Comment: @PuterdoBorato - The code won't notice any interrupts.

Comment: @StephenC, if we execute the mentioned code in thread and then call interrupt() on the thread? Why wouldn't it notice interrupts?

Comment: Because the only way to notice an interrupt is to check for it.  Most processes which block (using a lock, various IO streams, etc) will check the interrupt status and throw an exception so they do not run if the thread is supposed to be interrupted.  If you don't check for it, or use any code that checks for it, thread.interrupt() does nothing but set the interrupted flag.

Answer (score 2):

```
System.exit(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

In short words, `finally` block is not executed if JVM is stopped while thread is inside a corresponding `try` block, or if thread is killed using some low-level mechanisms (not `Thread.stop()`).

In addition to obvious examples with `System.exit()`, even a normal JVM shutdown can be unexpected for daemon threads:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final CountDownLatch c = new CountDownLatch(1);

    Thread t = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                System.out.println("Entering try block");
                c.countDown();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {}
            } finally {
                System.out.println("Never printed");
            }
        }
    };
    t.setDaemon(true);
    t.start();
    c.await();
    System.out.println("Exiting main thread");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also on my workout i found a new solution for this, is this can be accepcable

```
try {
if (choice) {
  while (true) ;
} else {
  System.exit(1);
}
} finally {
code.to.cleanup();
```

}