# `try` block help java

Tags: java, try-catch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there such case when in try\finally block the finally won't be executed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3484353/is-there-such-case-when-in-try-finally-block-the-finally-wont-be-executed)

I'm relatively new to java and I've just heard about `try-catch` blocks (3 minutes ago to be exact).

In a `try-catch` block, is the `finally` part (when present) ever **not** executed?

```
try {
    if (choice) {
        //...
    } else {
        //...
    }
} finally {
    doesThisEverNOTrun();
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there such case when in try\finally block the finally won't be executed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3484353/is-there-such-case-when-in-try-finally-block-the-finally-wont-be-executed) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6228528/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/464098/

Comment: [Yes](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/My-Tales.aspx). ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

```
try {
    if (choice) {
        while (true);
    } else {
        System.exit(0);
    }
} finally {
    doesThisEverNotRun(YES);
}
```

More often than not, though, the `finally` part is executed.

Comment: _"More often than not"_. Gee, that sure is a useful statement. `</sarcasm>`

Comment: @Matt Ball It actually *is* useful when you think about it :)

Comment: @Tony No problem! That's why we're here. :)

Comment: actually a try must have a `finally` OR a `catch` i.e. when there is a finally a catch is not mandatory

Comment: @ratchet freak LOL forgot about that. I'll change my answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

If the (virtual) machine does not crash, you don't call System.exit() in the try or a catch block, the finally block will execute.